Determining when two slopes are different or not, given heteroskedasticity
My current experiment investigates substrate consumption at two different substrate concentrations. My question concerns whether the slope of consumption is equal. However, I obtain an F-value indicating that the data is heteroskedastic. Which test would be most appropriate to use in this case?
Thank you in advance.
